# How to include dom-manipulating scripts into SSR Next.js App

Tags: node.js, next.js, webpack-dev-server

I am experiencing following error:

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "But I want to be altered by the client" Client: "Test"
    in div (at pages/index.tsx:17)
    in div (at pages/index.tsx:6)
    in HomePage (at _app.tsx:5)
    in MyApp
    in Container (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
```

... with the following setup:

A NextJS App Component:

```
function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <div id="test-div">I am rendered on the server.</div>
      <script src="http://localhost:8080/bundle.js"></script>
    </>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

(Note: The URL `http://localhost:8080/bundle.js` assumes webpack-dev-server is running and serving that resource)

The included "example" script:

```
const element = document.getElementById('test-div') as any;
element.innerHTML = 'But I want to be altered by the client';
```

In a simple setup I would just have a static html file, declaring a div element and including the "example" script.

But I would like to use NextJS, because I want to render dynamic (SSR) content into the page (eg. Text contents from a cms).

I noticed, that sometimes (if script execution takes some more ms of time), there is no error. Just do something time consuming in the example script.

Another hacky approach is to use `setTimeout` in the example script.
I don't want to do that until I know why this is happening:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  const element = document.getElementById('test-div') as any;
  element.innerHTML = 'But I want to be altered by the client';
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Next.js 11.0.0 and above

You can use [Next.js Script component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) to load third-party scripts.

```
// pages/index.js
import Script from 'next/script'

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" />
    </>
  )
}
```

With `next/script`, you can define the `strategy` property and Next.js will optimize loading for the script.

### Before Next.js 11.0.0

Browser and `document`, `window` objects are not available during server-side rendering.

You can initialize scripts that manipulate DOM after React component did mount.

```
useEffect(() => init(), [])
```

To add an external script you can do the following:

```
useEffect(() => require('../babylon.js'), [])
```

To include a script from another server you can add a `script` tag:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "http://localhost:8080/bundle.js";
  script.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
},[])
```

If you're adding DOM listeners you would also need to do cleanup.

[Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

[Effects with Cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)

Comment: Sure! That would be a solution. To just pull in the second project (the game) into the next app. And export the init function from it, to use it like you say. But I would like to keep the projects separate and agnostic. I just need the (server-)dynamically rendered next app presenting a canvas on which the game library can operate on. That's why I cannot use **init** in any lifecycle hooks. It is more the scenario like adding **jquery** to a statically rendered page afterwards.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, you can keep it separate and just add a script like you mentioned. I've updated the answer.

Comment: cool! I didn't think about doing this. I will try it out today, and tell you about the result!

Comment: :-( Nope. I didn't realize neither, when reading your answer. It is still not the right thing. Even with `useEffect(() => require('../babylon.js'), [])` the script will be executed in nextjs's scope. Yes, now on the client side after SSR. But now the game script is a code dependency of the nextjs project, which is not what I want. Also it is not possible to do sth like `require("http://localhost:8080/bundle.js");` of course. But I need hot reloading while developing the game code.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, I just realised that you meant your script is on another host. See the updated answer :)

Comment: That is not working. I also did try to create a script tag dynamically. The script is loading, but not executing. I will edit my question and put a simpler example in, which shows the same problem.

Comment: please see my **edited** and better understandable question.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, you don't need to add listener `DOMContentLoaded`.  By using `useEffect` hook you're appending script on a loaded page, so you already know that `document`, `window` and etc. are loaded. Try to remove listener and just execute the code. At the moment you're adding `DOMContentLoaded` when DOM is already loaded, so it's not executed

Comment: Jepp. But that is only a side effect. It is useless to listen to the DOMContentLoaded event, you are right. It was just an artifact from having the script in the head included. **But still the same results**. I also edited the question. Now without confusing listener.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, look, I've copied your example script and included it in `useEffect` as I mentioned and **it changed** the content of `test-div` to `But I want to be altered by the client`

Comment: Did you use NextJS for the ReactJS Part? I think in a typical React Application it is no problem.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, yes it's Next.js with Typescript setup.

Comment: And the included script: Is it served from another domain? In my case, the nextjs app is served from localhost:3000 and a webpack-dev-server is running on port 8080, from where I am including with `<script src="http://localhost:8080/bundle.js"></script>`

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, yes. Did you remove the script from `<Head></Head>`  anda added it to `useEffect`?

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, well, I would see the same error `Warning: Text content did not match.` **only** if I add a tag `<script></script>` to JSX (because it runs on server-side as well). But if it's added dynamically inside `useEffect` it executes correctly as it's only on a client-side. Maybe you left somewhere `<script></script>` in JSX.

Comment: thank you for tripple checking. You are totally right. It is working under the conditions you named. Thank you for investigating.

Comment: @EdgarAlloro, you're weclome.