# Run client-side script on NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js, mailchimp

I am trying to run a Mailchimp pop form script in my next.js application. And it seems the way next.js handles client-side scripts is causing errors to be thrown.

When I include this script in the `<Head>` like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) {L.start({ "baseUrl": "mc.us19.list-manage.com", "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "lid": "xxxxx", "uniqueMethods": true })})</script>
```

I get an error that

> "L" is not defined

When I wrap the content of the second script with a parenthesis like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">{window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) {L.start({ "baseUrl": "mc.us19.list-manage.com", "uuid": "xxxxxxxxxx", "lid": "xxxxx", "uniqueMethods": true })})}</script>
```

I get this error:

> "dojoRequire" is not a function

I have tried using react-helmet, but this had no effect. Some guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: You can add it inside `useEffect`. See explanation and example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296940/how-to-include-dom-manipulating-scripts-into-ssr-next-js-app/61300343#61300343.

Comment: @W.Bright Have you resolved this?. I am also facing the same issue with next js