# How to include js file in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am working with Reactjs,I want to link "js" file means i want to include
"js" file in my project but its not working, I put my code in "app.js" file,My js files exist
in "public" folder,I put code in "_app.js" file and Here is my current code in "_app.js" file

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../public/css/style.css'
import '../public/css/fonts.css'
import '../public/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../public/css/fonts2.css'
import Script from 'next/script'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
             <> 
                <script src="../js/core.min.js"></script>
                <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            </>
        );  
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include custom JS files in to React create app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44405718/how-to-include-custom-js-files-in-to-react-create-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include dom-manipulating scripts into SSR Next.js App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61296940/how-to-include-dom-manipulating-scripts-into-ssr-next-js-app)

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev no actually i dont want to add "third party scrips" i just want to include/use "js file" like we do in other framework

Comment: @Vyom, you can use the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61300343/5964023). It can be a local script too.

Comment: As mentioned, inject your script using `next/script`, e.g. `<Script src="/js/script.js" />`. Note that if you have your files in the public folder you should reference them as `/js/scripts.js` and `/js/core.min.js` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions described here:
[Add js script with react](https://betterprogramming.pub/4-ways-of-adding-external-js-files-in-reactjs-823f85de3668)

Here is one:

```js
import '../styles/globals.css'
import '../public/css/style.css'
import '../public/css/fonts.css'
import '../public/css/bootstrap.css'
import '../public/css/fonts2.css'
import Script from 'next/script'
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "../js/core.min.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    const script2 = document.createElement("script");
    script2.src = "../js/script.js";
    script2.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script2);
  return (
             <> 
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            </>
        );  
}

export default MyApp
```

Comment: Please tell me that we must include our "css/js/" file in "_app.js" file ?
And what should we write in _document.js, i am confuse between these two specially about "document.js"

Comment: You can also use "import 'file.js'"

Comment: as imported "css" files ?

Comment: its giving me following error

"ReferenceError: document is not defined"

Comment: After refresh page,css is not working fine